# Tensorflow error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to follow [Image Classification tutorial using Tensorflow and Kears](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) using a different dataset.

Please find X,Y details below:

```
print(train_images.shape, train_images.dtype, len(train_images))
print(train_labels.shape, train_labels.dtype, len(train_labels))

output:
(15, 150, 150, 3) <dtype: 'float32'> 15
(15, 8) <dtype: 'bool'> 15
```

Please find the model, compile and training code below. At the training stage, it failed with *list index out of scope* error.

```
BATCH_SIZE = 15
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = np.ceil(image_count/BATCH_SIZE)

train_data_gen = (train_images, train_labels)

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(8)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.summary()

Output:
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 150, 150, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 75, 75, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 75, 75, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 37, 37, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 37, 37, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 18, 18, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 20736)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 512)               10617344  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 4104      
=================================================================
Total params: 10,645,032
Trainable params: 10,645,032
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

# Getting this error while training the model
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_data_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=image_count // BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=15
)

error:
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-23-37be0256aa8a>:4: Model.fit_generator (from 
tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future 
version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use Model.fit, which supports generators.
Train on 15 samples
Epoch 1/15
 1/15 [=>............................] - ETA: 1s
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-37be0256aa8a> in <module>
      2     train_data_gen,
      3     steps_per_epoch=image_count // BATCH_SIZE,
----> 4     epochs=15
      5 )



IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'll appreciate any explanation for above error.

Changed *train_data_gen* in X and Y arrays. After this change, I was getting below error

```
TypeError: fit_generator() got multiple values for argument 
'steps_per_epoch'
```

A quick google search told me if X and Y are specified separately, len(Y) gets assigned to *steps_per_epoch* as value(need to read more about it). After commenting out *steps_per_epoch*, I got below error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The Y(image_label) array was np bool. So, tried to create a float array using below:

```
train_labels_float = np.empty([BATCH_SIZE], dtype=float)
for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
  label_index = np.where(train_labels[i] == True)
  np.append(train_labels_float,label_index[0][0])

print(train_labels_float.shape, train_labels_float.dtype, 
len(train_labels_float))

output:
(15,) float64 15
```

But still getting the same error:

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_images,
    train_labels_float,
    #steps_per_epoch=image_count // BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=15
)

error:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is 
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Kindly explain the error and suggest how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found that your `STEPS_PER_EPOCH = np.ceil(image_count/BATCH_SIZE)` while what you put in `fit_generator` was `steps_per_epoch=image_count // BATCH_SIZE`. I guess if you use `steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH` might solve the problem since **np.ceil(10 / 7) = 2** and **10 // 7 = 1** which are not the same.

Comment: still getting the same error after changing `steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH`

Comment: Oops! I got one thing missed. Does change ```STEPS_PER_EPOCH = np.ceil(image_count/BATCH_SIZE) ``` to ```STEPS_PER_EPOCH = image_count // BATCH_SIZE ``` solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better format your label into one-hot style according to your classify kinds, since there're 8 labels in your output, it should be like [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0].
And, do you set the validation samples?

Comment: Used this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) to create the dataset using Dataset.map and changed loss functional to `CategoricalCrossentropy`. Training is now getting completed. Thanks.